# Odoo - how to stop show barcode in picking operations report

Tags: barcode, odoo-15

I enabled LOT/SERIAL NUMBER.

And when I tried to print picking operations report, the LOT/SERIAL NUMBER field show me a barcode.

I just need the number, how can I stop print the barcode out? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to not show the barcode, you need to modify the report template accordingly. The report template to be changed here is the one with id `report_picking`. YOu can either create a new module to inherit this template and XPath and remove the t-options in the below line

```
<div t-if="has_serial_number and (ml.lot_id or ml.lot_name)" t-esc="ml.lot_id.name or ml.lot_name" t-options="{'widget': 'barcode', 'humanreadable': 1, 'width': 400, 'height': 100, 'img_style': 'width:100%;height:35px;'}"/>
```

Or you can go to Technical settings, select views and search for this particular id and edit the same from front end itself